# Creating a query that produces a sum and outputs it in a single row

Tags: google-bigquery

This is the code I have been running:

```
SELECT
   Model,
   Serial,
   SUM(ConnectionTime) OVER(ORDER BY Serial)
FROM [dataworks-356fa:FirebaseArchive.test8]
WHERE Model == "BlueBox-pH"
```

However, when I do this, it provides the sum in multiples rows for every repeat of the Model. Even if I take out Model and change the `WHERE` clause to the serial number it still produces the same thing numerous times.

What code should I add to make sure each serial number is unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a window function to SUM your values. This causes the row duplication. Is there any specific reason for doing the SUM like that?

Usually a SUM would go like this:

```
SELECT
    Model,
    Serial,
    SUM(ConnectionTime)
FROM
    [dataworks-356fa:FirebaseArchive.test8]
WHERE
    Model == "BlueBox-pH"
GROUP BY
    Model,
    Serial
```

This will output a single row for every unique combination of Model and Serial with the SUM of ConnectionTime.